# Android Time Format Parsing

Tags: android, date-format, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse the time which comes from server but it throws "java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date" exception. Here is my code, what is wrong with that ?

```
 String sdate="2014-07-30T22:24:38.384054+03:00";
 final String sformat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ";
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(sformat);
 Date now = format.parse(sdate);
```

Another thing is sometimes server time returns like this "2014-07-30T22:24:05.0191947+03:00" but both situation gives me same same error.(I know there is 7 digits on second example so this is also an issue which i have to take care of I think.)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
final String sformat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX"
```

If you check the docs, the 'Z' at the end doesn't have a ':' colon character, while 'XXX' does.

Answer (score 0):

I would Try removing the fractional seconds from the format string.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
```

This should work on all fractional seconds you might get.